# Simple Html Dom : parsing never ends

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

This script nevers ends - load method cannot achieve parsing :

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://chevaux-normandie.com/directory/listing/haras-des-coudraies');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$dom = new simple_html_dom();

$dom->load($str);
```

(code works with all other urls I've tried)

Edit : I want to use curl, but doing so would work otherwise :

```
$html = file_get_html('http://chevaux-normandie.com/directory/listing/haras-des-coudraies');
```

Comment: There's is __no looping__ here.

Comment: To be more precised : The script never ends